# Ios web view page loading error

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiwebview

Error `Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017` `"cannot parse response"` I got this error when I load a html page into the webview. Can anyone give me a solution

Comment: Can you please explain with your code

Comment: Did you provided proper path to HTML file ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Change "sample" with your file name. You might not be getting path which might be the issue.

Hope this helps :)